# How do I convert existing code from Pandas to Dask?

Tags: pandas, dask, dot-product

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000000, size=(1000000, 55)), columns=(selected))/100000
df = df.div(xf.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

ret = df.dot(returns_annualR) #returns_annualR is a pandas series (55x1)
var_matrix = np.dot(np.dot(df, cov_matrixR),df.T) #cov_matrixR is a pandas dataframe (55x55)
d1 = dd.dot(df.T).min().abs()
```

When I use Pandas and Numpy - the code fails with "**Memory Error**".  I have only 16GB of RAM.

I was wondering if the above code could be implemented using Dask.  I understand this maybe a good task for the Dask i.e. large dataframes.  I have tried to, but dont seem to have much success (I'm relatively new to Dask).

For example I converted "df" to Dask as follows:

```
xf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000000, size=(num_portfolios, num_assets)), columns=(selected))/100000
xf = xf.div(xf.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

dd_test = dd.from_pandas(xf, npartitions=40).compute()

returns1 = returns_annualR.to_numpy() #convert to numpy array
returns1 = dd_test.dot(returns1).compute()
```

It fails when I try to do the dot product and get the following error: **'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dot'**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? It's not clear what `returns_annualR` is/does.

Comment: hi rpanai - thanks for responding.  "returns_annualR" is 55x1 matrix(pandas series) of floats.  Essentially, I am trying to obtain the dot product of "returns_annualR" and df.  "df" is a 1Milx55 matrix.  Essentially, I would end up getting 1Milx1 matrix, each row being a weighted average of the returns i.e. 1Mil randomly weighted values.